# Regular 2D array vs Dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

Does a regular array need to be initialized when it is created? If it is default initialized is it not possible to change the elements in an array?

When creating a 2D array, all the examples I see are using dynamic memory. Is it because the dynamically allocated 2D array does not need to be initialized. Is it possible to fill the array elements after declaring a regular 2D array?

Comment: Initialization and storage class are by-and-large unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

- no, a static array needs no initialization ("needs" meaning you don't have to give one. Of course you *should* consider initial values depending on your problem).
- You can change all values always. Just use e.g. `my_array[2][3] = 42` to assign the value.
- people are using dynamically alocated memory whenever the array size is unknown at compile time or changes over time. Allocated memory is not initialized, therefore it's your responsibility to provide good default values.

Read more at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: It's worth noting that the cited site is notorious for erroneous content. Prefer a better source, such as [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).